# Prestashop attributes on change - related attributes display

Tags: php, mysql, attributes, prestashop-1.6

I have some problem in product attributes selection.. One product have 2 attributes - like Purity, Weight

```
Purity - 14kt, 18kt
Weight - 3gms, 4gms, 10gms, 12gms

==============================================================

14kt have only - 3gms, 4gms
18kt have only - 10gms, 12gms

==============================================================
```

When i click on product detail and quick view page.. All the weight will appear. When i change the purity "This combination does not exist for this product. Please select another combination." Error will comes, but

i need display only related products attribute only.. for example default
14kt - 3gms, 4gms

When i change
18kt - 10gms, 12gms

After i change
14kt - 3gms, 4gms

Any one know this code changes, please help me.. site URL is: http://navaratnamaaligai.com/necklaces/9-necklace-02.html

Answer (score 0):

You will need to show the code and preferably the table but it seems that the error message is not a system error but a programmed error response indicating that that product is not available with that purity

Comment: yes i know that... but how can display only related products attribute only.

Comment: Really you need to show the code.  I am not familiar with Pretashop only PHP and Mysql which were also tagged in your question it probably will need you to change the SELECT query so you only show certain products.  Sorry but I don't think you will get an answer without the relevant code.